# Unable to start single node cluster of Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to install `hadoop 2.9.1` on `ubuntu 19.10` and I did all steps explained in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6oit3rCsZo

The problem is that when I triyed to start single node cluster using this command :

```
hduser@-ubuntu:~$ start-dfs.sh
```

I get this error :

> localhost: chown: modification of the owner of
>   '/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/logs': Operation not allowed

I searched and I find some solutions given in ["Permission denied" errors whe starting a single node cluster in Hadoop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37786/permission-denied-errors-whe-starting-a-single-node-cluster-in-hadoop)

and in [namenode not running... i have already tried sudo chown -R username /usr/local/hadoop/ please help](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814564/namenode-not-running-i-have-already-tried-sudo-chown-r-username-usr-local-h)

So I tried to solve the problem using :

1- `hduser@-ubuntu:~$ chown -R hduser /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/`

which return

> chown: modification du propriétaire de
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs/yarn-imed-resourcemanager-imed-bigdata-ubuntu.out':
>   Opération non permise chown: modification du propriétaire de
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs/SecurityAuth-imed.audit':
>   Opération non permise chown: modification du propriétaire de
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs/userlogs': Opération non permise
>   chown: modification du propriétaire de
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs/yarn-imed-resourcemanager-imed-bigdata-ubuntu.log':
>   Opération non permise
>
> chown: modification of the owner of
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs/yarn-imed-resourcemanager-imed-bigdata-ubuntu.out':
>   Operation not allowed chown: modification of the owner of
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs/SecurityAuth-imed.audit':
>   Operation not allowed chown: modification of the owner of
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs/userlogs': Operation not allowed
>   chown: modification of the owner of
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs/yarn-imed-resourcemanager-imed-bigdata-ubuntu.log':
>   Operation not allowed

2- I tried this command :

```
hduser@-ubuntu:~$ chmod 777 /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/
```

And I get

> chmod: modification of the rights of
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/': Operation not allowed

3- I added `sudo` in each time like `sudo chmod 777 /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/`
and I get :

```
[sudo] Mot de passe de hduser :
```

> chmod: modification of dhduser does not appear in the sudoers file.
>   This event will be reported. roits de
>   '/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/': Operation not allowed

4-Finally, I run the cluster node using `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/sbin/start-dfs.sh` instead. But, I got the same error !

> Starting namenodes on [localhost] localhost: chown: modification of
>   the owner of '/usr/local/hadoop-2.9.1/logs': Operation not allowed

Note that my `start-dfs.sh` file is :

```
 <configuration>
    <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
    </property>

    <property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>file:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoopdata/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
    </configuration>
```

And `./.bashrc` file contiens these parameters :

```
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export YARN_HOME=${HADOOP_HOME}
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop

#Native path
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=${HADOOP_HOME}/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_PREFIX/lib/native"

#Java path
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_251"
```

PLease, how can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the solution was that I should include the `hduser` in the `hadoopgroup` to have permission on the folder `/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs`
using the command :

```
sudo chown -R hduser:hadoopgroup /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.9.1/logs
```

That resolve my problem !